# Partial derivative of a convolution

Tags: integration, partial-derivative, convolution

I have some doubts regarding the following partial derivative:

\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial}{\partial x(t)} \int_{t_0}^{t} h(t-\tau) x(\tau)\, \mathrm{d}\tau.
\end{equation}

Assuming that $h(t)$ is the impulse response of a causal and stable linear system, and that $x(t)$ is the system input, I am tempted to do something like:
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial}{\partial x(t)} \int_{t_0}^{t} h(t-\tau) x(\tau)\, \mathrm{d}\tau = \int_{t_0}^{t} h(t-\tau)\dot{x}(\tau) \, \mathrm{d}\tau.
\end{equation}
Because of the linearity of the convolution operator, and because variations in the input ($x(t)$) can be represented as time-varying variations.  However, applying Leibnitz I get:
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial t \partial}{\partial x(t) \partial t} \int_{t_0}^{t} h(t-\tau) x(\tau)\, \mathrm{d}\tau &= \frac{1}{\partial{x}(t)/\partial{t}}\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\int_{t_0}^{t} h(t-\tau)x(\tau) \, \mathrm{d}\tau = \, ... \\
= \frac{1}{\dot{x}(t)} \left[h(0)x(t) + \int_{t_0}^{t} \dot{h}(t-\tau) x(\tau)\, \mathrm{d}\tau \right] &= \frac{1}{\dot{x}(t)} \left[h(0)x(t) + \int_{t_0}^{t} {h}(t-\tau) \dot{x}(\tau)\, \mathrm{d}\tau \right].
\end{align}

I sincerely appreciate any assistance with this.

Cheers!

Comment: $L:x\mapsto h*x$ is linear and continuous, hence its differential at any point $x$ is itself. $DL_x(k)=L(k).$

Comment: Do you really mean $\partial/\partial x$, or do you mean $\partial/\partial t$?

Comment: If you mean $\partial/\partial t,$ or rather $d/dt$ ($h$ and $x$ being fixed functions), apply the usual https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule

Comment: Thank you for your comments. First, I would like to clarify that the derivative is with respect to $x(t)$. The question arises from an optimisation problem; hence, the partial derivative with respect to $x(t)$ appears. I understand that due to the linearity in the operator, I could get the operator itself.

However, I do not quite understand why (if possible), using Leibniz as:
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial t}{\partial x} \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \int_{t_0}^{t} h(t-\tau) x(\tau)\, \mathrm{d}\tau
\end{equation}
I do not get the same result (To summarise I do not copy the answer).

Comment: @AnneBauval thank you for your comments. Based on your feedback I have now updated my question.

Comment: $\frac{\partial t}{\partial x}$ makes no sense, and $\frac{1}{\dot{x}}\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\ne\frac{\partial}{\partial x}.$ Based on my first comment above, $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\int_{t_0}^{t} h(t-\tau) x(\tau)\, \mathrm{d}\tau\right)$ is not $\int_{t_0}^{t} h(t-\tau)\, \mathrm{d}\tau.$ It is the map
$$k\mapsto\int_{t_0}^{t} h(t-\tau) k(\tau)\, \mathrm{d}\tau.$$

Comment: I have taken my time to try to conceptually understand your answer. First, $x(t)$ is a function of $t$, so why is it that $(\partial{x}/ \partial{t})^{-1}$ makes no sense? I am sorry if I am asking something too simple. Second, in your reply, what would $k$ represent?
I am trying to determine the variations in the output of a system $y(t)$ with respect to variations in the input $x(t)$. It is natural to think that this derivative could be computed, and an analytical expression found. I sincerely appreciate your time, so if you could recommend some readings I could continue from there.